# Relative numbers, bouncing text?

Tags: line-numbers

when I put relative numbers on, I get bouncing text when I move up an down.

I have short files where this is an issue, so it's not the number length. The entire line reshapes depending on the "width" of the number.

I tried a wider number column, but it's the same effect.

When i turn off

Here is my init.el:

```
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1) ;; line numbers globally
(setq display-line-numbers-width 3)
(setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative)
```

Emacs 28.2

Comment: Perhaps you should share a screenshot? When I try to reproduce it locally, I don’t see anything like what you describe.

Comment: It's hard to show the issue in a screenshot. I created a gif but I cannot upload gif's to SE.

Comment: Then take two screenshots, one before and one after.

Comment: What font are you using? Can it be the different number digits have different widths in that font?

Comment: Good question, I am using jetbrains mono. Yeah, they defo have different widths. I will try another font.

Comment: If it is tagged "mono", that would imply "monospace" (aka fixed-width) to me. Are you sure that they have different widths?